# i want to find the frequent letters

Tags: c

in that programm i will give 6 names and then i want to find from the whole names the frequent characters . I tried this but it doesn't show me the character from all the names but the whole name insteed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 6

int main()
{


    char name[max][20];
    char *ptrnaame;
    int i,j,len, cnt, k, next, occurence=0, maximum=0;
    char *index_max=NULL;


    ptrname=name[0];

    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        printf("Give the name :");
        gets(name[i]);
        len=strlen(name[i]);
        while(len>20)
        {
            printf("Give the name again:");
            gets(name[i]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        occurence=0;
        for(j=i; j<20; j++)
        {
            if(!strcmp(*(name+i), *(name+j)))
            {
                occurence++;
            }
        }
        if(occurence>maximum)
        {
            maximum=occurence;
            index_max=*(name+i);
        }
    }
    if(index_max!=NULL)
    {
        printf("The most frequent character is: %s with %d occurences", index_max, maximum);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What logic are using to count the frequencies?

Comment: If you want to find out which letter occurs most often, you must keep track of the occurrences of all letters. That means you need an array of counts, not just a scalar. And if you just want to count the occurrences of letters, you don't have to store the names, just process them, that is count their letters, as they come.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing a string (`%s`) instead of a character (`%c`).

**Try this**

```
printf("The most frequent character is: %c with %d occurences", index_max[0], maximum);
```

Comment: it gives me a letter but it isn't  the frequent letter

Comment: You are using `strcmp()`. This is used for comparing strings, not characters. Try this instead: `if(*(name+i) == *(name+j))`.

Comment: That would be just comparing two pointers. You would need to de-reference again to get the character value. Using indexes would read better.

Comment: i did what you said but again it doesnt give the letter

Comment: Try this instead: `if(**(name+i) == **(name+j))`

Comment: in the printf i'm gonna use index_max[0]; ?

Comment: @user5624945: It does not work, because the whole logic of your program is wrong. Take a step back, look at what your program does and then at what you wat to achieve. Fixing small things in a program that is fundamentally broken won't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has errors that others have already pointed out. The biggest error is that the program's logic is not correct.

I reckon that if your names are Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dora, Emily and Frank, you want the output to be E, which occurs most often across all names, namely 4 times.

If so, then you must count the occurences of all characters. There are many possible ways to do that. You could loop over all letters and then over all words and their letters and increment the count when the letter matches. That is straightforward, but rather inefficient, because you process the data 26 times.

A better way might be to keep an array of counts for the letters. Then you need to inspect each word and each letter only once: Look at the character and if it is a letter, increment the according count.

A nice side effect is that now you don't need to store the names anymore. Let the letters stream in from `stdin` as the user types them, process them and immediately forget about them. You are only interested in the total count of each letter.

Not storing the names also means that you don't run into memory management problems anymore. For example, in your original code you want to loop over the letters in each word from 0 up to 20, but there aren't necessarily that many letters in the word. The char buffer holds valid input only up to the terminating null character; everything after that is garbage. You also mistakenly use the letter index as index for the words, of which there are only six. That leads to bad memory accesses.

Here's an example implementation that lets you input as many names as you like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int count[26] = {0};        // counts for 26 letters
    char line[80];              // line buffer
    int i;

    puts("[Please enter text. A blank line or Ctrl-D/Z ends input.]");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        int nonspace = 0;

        for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            int c = line[i];

            if ('A' < c && c <= 'Z') count[c - 'A']++;
            if ('a' < c && c <= 'z') count[c - 'a']++;
            if (c != ' ' && c != '\n') nonspace++;
        }

        if (nonspace == 0) break;
    }

    int imax = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        if (count[i] > count[imax]) {
            imax = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Most frequent character is %c (occurs %d times).\n",
        'A' + imax, count[imax]);

    return 0;
}
```